# linux:extract specific words using awk,grep or sed

Tags: bash, awk

Looking to extract Specific Words from each line

```
Nov  2 11:25:51 imau03ftc CSCOacs_TACACS_Accounting 0687979272 1 0 2016-11-02 11:25:51.250 +13:00 0311976914 3300 NOTICE Tacacs-Accounting: TACACS+ Accounting with Command, ACSVersion=acs-5.6.0.22-B.225, ConfigVersionId=145, Device IP Address=10.107.32.53, CmdSet=[ CmdAV=show controllers <cr> ], RequestLatency=0, Type=Accounting, Privilege-Level=15, Service=Login, User=nc-rancid, Port=tty1, Remote-Address=172.26.200.204, Authen-Method=TacacsPlus, AVPair=task_id=8280, AVPair=timezone=NZDT, AVPair=start_time=1478039151, AVPair=priv-lvl=1, AcctRequest-Flags=Stop, Service-Argument=shell, AcsSessionID=imau03ftc/262636280/336371030, SelectedAccessService=Default Device Admin, Step=13006 , Step=15008 , Step=15004 , Step=15012 , Step=13035 , NetworkDeviceName=CASWNTHS133, NetworkDeviceGroups=All Devices:All Devices, NetworkDeviceGroups=Device Type:All Device Types:Corporate, NetworkDeviceGroups=Location:All Locations, Response={Type=Accounting; AcctReply-Status=Success; }
```

Looking to extract 
`Nov  2 11:25:51 show controllers User=nc-rancid NetworkDeviceName=CASWNTHS133` 
can use awk,grep or sed

i have tried few combinations like

`sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/tacacs/imau03ftc-accounting.log | grep -oP 'User=\K.*' & 'NetworkDeviceName=\K.*'`

`sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/tacacs/imau03ftc-accounting.log | sudo awk -F" " '{ print $1 " " $3 " " $9 " " $28}'`

i can add few more lines but most of them have same format

thanks

Comment: You say, *looking to extract specific words from each line* yet you have provided only a single line. What have you tried? Post something showing that you have at least **tried** to do this yourself.

Comment: see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Edit you question showing what you have tried. And as Cyrus said, take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Is this all in one single line as you have presented it here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this:

```
sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/tacacs/imau03ftc-accounting.log > tmpfile
```

Then execute this script:

```
  #!/bin/sh

   while read i
   do
     str=""
     str="$(echo $i |awk '{print $1,$2,$3}')"
     str="$str $(echo $i |awk 'match($0, /CmdAV=([^<]+)/) { print substr( $0, RSTART,RLENGTH  ) }'|awk -F "=" '{print $2}')"
     str="$str $(echo $i |awk 'match($0, /User=([^,]+)/) { print substr( $0, RSTART, RLENGTH  ) }')"
     str="$str $(echo $i |awk 'match($0, /NetworkDeviceName=([^,]+)/) { print substr( $0, RSTART, RLENGTH  ) }')"

     echo $str
  done < tmpfile
```

Output:

```
Nov 2 11:25:51 show controllers User=nc-rancid NetworkDeviceName=CASWNTHS133
```